# Python fCGI + sqlAlchemy = malformed header from script. Bad header=FROM tags : index.py

Tags: python, mysql, apache, sqlalchemy, fastcgi

I'm writing an Fast-CGI application that makes use of sqlAlchemy & MySQL for persistent data storage.  I have no problem connecting to the DB and setting up ORM (so that tables get mapped to classes); I can even add data to tables (in memory).

But, as soon as I query the DB (and push any changes from memory to storage) I get a **500 Internal Server Error** and my error.log records **malformed header from script. Bad header=FROM tags : index.py**, when *tags* is the table name.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Also, I don't think it matters, but its a Linux development server talking to an off-site (across the country) MySQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like SQLalchemy is pushing or echoing the query to your output (where fast-cgi) is instead looking for headers, then body.  Maybe setting sqlalchemy.echo to False can help.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  I had echo set to True from earlier debugging & didn't realize it would mess up F-CGI

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `echo=True` you can configure logging to output debugging information. SQLAlchemy has very flexible [loggers hierarchy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/dbengine.html#configuring-logging). The following lines will enable logging of the same info as `echo` does:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```